# Проблема В Inner Join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть список документов. Они записываются в таблице `POLICIES`. Копия документов сохраняется в таблице `DOCS`. При утере документа создается дубликат документа и он сохраняется в обеих таблицах, но связь между оригиналом и дубликатом есть только в таблице `POLICIES` по полям **policy_id** и **policy_id_parent**.

И мой запрос **№1** по выводу всех дубликатов выглядит так:

```
Select p.policy_id, p.policy_id_parent
from POLICIES p
Inner Join DOCS d On d.ExtId = p.policy_id
Inner Join DOCS d1 On d1.ExtId = p.policy_id_parent
Where p.contract_operation_type_id = 4 and p.policy_id_parent is not null
```

здесь `p.contract_operation_type_id = 4` это условие для дубликатов.

Запрос **№1** мне ничего не выводит, хотя мой запрос **№2** выводит оба поля соответственно. Мне нужны данные об оригинал документах.

```
Select p.policy_id, p.policy_id_parent
from POLICIES p
Inner Join DOCS d On d.ExtId = p.policy_id
Where p.contract_operation_type_id = 4 and p.policy_id_parent is not null
```

Я знаю по запросу **№2** что существуют в Базе дубликаты. Но не могу вывести их методом **№1**.

**Почему запрос №1 ничего не выводит?**

Comment: Если запрос 2 выводит вам записи, а запрос 1 не выводит - значит в `Docs` нет записей с соответствующими ExtId. Проверить, в общем-то, несложно: `select * from Docs where ExtId in (select policy_id_parent from policies where p.contract_operation_type_id=4)`. Посмотрите, что возвращает этот запрос.

Comment: @Zufir, оказывается вы правы.